# How to update recycler view in first activity while changing data in other activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a todolist application with sqlite. I have created a recycler view in main activity and a other activity to add a new todo. But when I add todo I want to refresh the recycler view how can I do it? 
Please Help

---

Video - https://i.imgur.com/iYgqBYN.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Place the code where you fetching and setting data inside recycler view in `onResume()` method. So whenever you add a new item to the database and go back to previous activity it will fetch new data again.

Answer (score 0):

In your **adapter class** extending RecyclerView.Adapter<> you should create ArrayList<> of your Todo objects. Adapter class should also contain method to add Todos, something like

```
ArrayList<Todo> todos = new ArrayList()<>;
public void addNewTodo(Todo newTodo) {
        todos.add(todo); // add new todo
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // update RecyclerView
    }
```

Then in your **other** (not main) Activity you can call this public method through your Adapter class:

```
private MyAdapter adapter;
private Todo newTodo;
adapter = new MyAdapter(...);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

newTodo = createTodo(); // Initialize your Todo object
adapter.addNewTodo(newTodo); // Add new todo and update RecyclerView
```